# JWT not found either in the 'Authorization' HTTP request headers

Tags: java, spring, rest, authorization, client

I've created a Client to consume a Rest API. Everything seems to be OK but I'm getting an 401 error as the JWT was not found.
Here is the service which I've made:

```
@Service
public class RestTemplateService {

    private static final String GET_RELATION_BY_ID = "https://cuco-query-sbg-cuco-dev.apps.scg01.scg.dev.bo2.paas.cloudcenter.corp/getRelationByCucoId/{cucoId}";
    private static final String JWT = "Bearer xxxx"

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public ResponseEntity<CuCoPerson> getRelationById(Integer cucoId) {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.add("Authorization", JWT);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
        Map<String, Integer> param = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        param.put("cucoId", cucoId);
        return restTemplate.exchange(GET_RELATION_BY_ID, HttpMethod.GET, entity, CuCoPerson.class, param);

    }
}
```

And here the controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/getRelationById/{cucoId}")
    public ResponseEntity<CuCoPerson> getRelationByCucoId(@PathVariable Integer cucoId, @AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal) {
        return restTemplateService.getRelationById(cucoId);
    }
```

So, where I'm failing to get that TOKEN?

Thanks in advance!!